# Do we need replicaSet in connection URI of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

When connecting to mongo cluster do we need replicaSet option in connection URI like below

```
mongodb://db1.example.net:27017,db2.example.net:2500/?replicaSet=test
```

What happens if replicaSet option is not used but all the nodes are given in connection URI like below

```
mongodb://db1.example.net:27017,db2.example.net:2500/
```

What is the advantage of giving and not giving replicaSet in the connection URI for the above 2 cases.

Comment: Specifying all the nodes and the replica-set name in the connection string uri - _is a best practice_. Note that the `replicaSet` option specifies the unique name for the replica-set (as defined in the replica-set configuration). I guess it is easy to identify one with an easily human readable name and that all the nodes belong to it. This applies where ever the connection string uri is specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always recommended to  include the `replicaSet` in the MongoDB connection String URI Format as a best practice. Enabling this will help to explore much more options for better application connectivity.

*Advantages of including replicaSet:*

1. Once enabled the client/driver will be aware of the all `other members` in the replica set.
2. If fail-over occurs client/driver `automatically connects` to next available member with zero downtime.
3. Using readConcern we can `scale the reads` better with other replica members.

> replicaSet=myRepl&readConcernLevel=majority

4. To acknowledge all the write operation we can use `write concern` along with the URI

> replicaSet=myRepl&w=majority&wtimeoutMS=5000

5. We can enable the `connection timeout` to maintain a better connectivity.

> replicaSet=test&connectTimeoutMS=200000

6. Securing the application to use only `TLS/SSL` encrypted connections.

> replicaSet=myRepl&ssl=true

For better secured application support and connectivity always use the replicaSet on connection String URI.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify also the replicaSet.

If you don't specify the replicaSet then you still connect to the PRIMARY node. However, in case the PRIMARY becomes unavailable then your connection is lost. If you specify the replicaSet then the client will automatically re-connect to the new primary member.

You an play around and make test with these commands:

- `db.hello().primary` returns the current primary member
- `db.hostInfo().system.hostname` returns the member where you are currently connected to

Answer (score 0):

if you have an endpoint like: `mongodb+srv://username:password@mycluster.mik05g.mongodb.net`

run the nslookup CLI

> > 

```
nslookup -type=TXT mycluster.mik05g.mongodb.net
Server:        127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
mycluster.mik05g.mongodb.net    text = "authSource=admin&replicaSet=MyCluster-shard-0"
```

So the replicaSet name here is: `MyCluster-shard-0`